# Google Identity Toolkit returns error 2 when signing in with aol email Id

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I have been using Google Identity Toolkit for my GAE (Java) based app for couple years now. I have Google, Facebook and Microsoft federated logins enabled. However, when a user tries to "Sign In with Email" and uses an `@aol.com` account, it returns a 503 error, and `Error code: Error code: 2.` error message on the UI. In the console, the following errors appear:

```
gitkit.js:242 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=<key> 503 ()
lj.send @ gitkit.js:242
Mj @ gitkit.js:255
Lj.requestGitkitEndpoint @ gitkit.js:256
Oj.createAuthUri @ gitkit.js:258
N @ gitkit.js:190
Vm @ gitkit.js:337
(anonymous) @ gitkit.js:338
(anonymous) @ gitkit.js:79
(anonymous) @ gitkit.js:77
Yc @ gitkit.js:44
g.dispatchEvent @ gitkit.js:42
g.handleEvent @ gitkit.js:70
Mc.a.(anonymous function).a.(anonymous function) @ gitkit.js:41
Uc @ gitkit.js:39
Rc @ gitkit.js:41
Pc.b @ gitkit.js:37
gitkit.js:254  [ 40.291s] [identitytoolkit] createAuthUri: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Error code: 2"}],"code":503,"message":"Error code: 2"}}
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Hey DFB, can you provide more information? Did you previously have AOL provider enabled for your project? Was this previously working and just suddenly stopped working?

Comment: Hello @bojeil , I never had AOL enabled as a provider for my project. The email/password login option for aol account was working fine until about a week ago. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: It seems like this is related to AOL shutting down their OIDC service. Google Identity Toolkit team is working on a fix to bypass this. It should be resolved on its own. No action would be needed on your end. You can file a support ticket if you want to track it.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks for the update. How do I file a support ticket for identity toolkit?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I actually do not know. Try filing a request via Firebase support. GITKit was deprecated in favor of Firebase Auth.

Comment: @bojeil I guess, I'll wait for your update on this thread. Hope the issue is resolved soon. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @DFB, it should be working now.

Comment: @bojeil I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I can't reproduce it from my end. I pass an @aol.com email when asked for the email and it works as expected, I get redirected to sign up with the requested email.

Comment: @bojeil today when I checked, it seems to be working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to AOL shutting down their OIDC service. Google Identity Toolkit team applied a fix to bypass it. The issue was resolved without any code change from my end. Thanks to @bojeil for help.