# Google Identity Toolkit failing to log in AOL email: Error code: 2

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

Trying to log in using the Google Identity Toolkit with an AOL email returns "Error code: Error code: 2.":

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=<key> 503 ()

[identitytoolkit] createAuthUri: {"error":{"code":503,"message":"Error code: 2","errors":[{"message":"Error code: 2","domain":"global","reason":"backendError"}]}}
```

No opportunity to enter in a password. This error is shown prior to getting the chance to enter your PW. I do not have AOL enabled as one of my login providers in my config and this was previously working for users. Looks like the same issue was discussed in this post: [Google Identity Toolkit returns error 2 when signing in with aol email Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340899/google-identity-toolkit-returns-error-2-when-signing-in-with-aol-email-id?rq=1) 
It seems to be an issue still or broke again. Anyone know how to resolve?

Comment: Hey @yaryar123, can you provide your project number? This error should not happen anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340899/google-identity-toolkit-returns-error-2-when-signing-in-with-aol-email-id

Comment: Here you go @bojeil, 566131363142. Thanks for looking into this! I did just confirm I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: I have filed a bug for this (confirmed as a bug). The previously Google Identity Toolkit backend team is looking into it.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil much appreciated